# How can you create a three.js geometry that is equivalent to looking over the earths surface?

Tags: three.js

I'd like to create a geometry similar to something what's done in this shader:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms2SD1

Where you are essentially looking over the surface of the earth, and it's slighty curved around all the axes. I don't want to create geometry for the entire sphere, but just for the surface that is visible.

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Rather than curving the geometry, it looks like they're using a fish-eye effect on the camera.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6xaL9a1d/

Comment: This looks better: http://jsfiddle.net/uLzzshxc/

Comment: If those are what you tried so far post them in your question as a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

In the SphereGeometry constructor you can specify how what part of the sphere you want. For example, if you want to top part of the sphere, you can use:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 16, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI/4);
```

You can experiment with the last 4 arguments and check the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/SphereGeometry) for more information.

To get it less curved you can just give the sphere a bigger radius.

Here is an example:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 16, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI/4);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        wireframe: true
    });
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );

sphere.position.y -= 3;
camera.position.z = 4;
camera.rotation.x -= Math.PI / 9

var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: On second thought, depending on your requirements, maybe even a CircleGeometry would be enough? just tried it and placing the camera over a flat circle makes it look like a curved horizon. It will not work as well with lighting and such though.